# Asteroids game. Program doesn't allow for pressing of left, up, and space keys simultaneously

Tags: gml

I'm writing a basic asteroids game. Here is my object screen for my spaceship object

[image]

The code in each of my actions is

```
//Step
speed = max(speed - 0.01, 0);

//Left 
image_angle += 2;

//Right
image_angle -= 2;

//Outside Room
//Drag and drop item: wrap screen

//press Space
bullet = instance_create(x, y, obj_bullet);
bullet.direction = image_angle;
bullet.speed = 15;
```

The problem is that when I hold both the right and up keys, I can shoot using the 
spacebar. However, when I'm holding the left and up keys, and press space bar, it doesn't shoot. Why is that?

I hope I have provided enough info here. If it's not enough, please let me know.
Posting code here is a lot more work than posting code for a C program.

Comment: That sounds like a limitation of your keyboard. A lot of keyboards suck like that.

Comment: Ok. Will look into it. Thanks

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having separate event handlers, try using keyboard_check(key) in the step event. IE: remove or comment out the code in the left, up, right and space actions, and include in the step event something like...

```
//Speed
speed = max(speed - 0.01, 0);

//Turn
image_angle += ((keyboard_check(vk_right)-keyboard_check(vk_left)*2);

//Shoot
if keyboard_check_pressed(vk_space)
{
bullet = instance_create(x, y, obj_bullet);
bullet.direction = image_angle;
bullet.speed = 15;
}
```

Hope it works :)